# What's the difference between "umbrage", "offense" and "affront"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

What's the difference between "umbrage", "offense" and "affront"? Is it like only the second word is now in use?

Comment: All three are in use currently. At least in the UK anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget *affront*, *insult*, *indignity*, or *outrage*, which all suggest provocation, impertinence, offense, rudeness.

> These words express disrespect shown in a way that is, or is meant to
>   be, galling. An *affront* is generally open and to the face. An
>   *insult* is stronger, perhaps accompanied by more insolence of manner; it is a deeper disgrace and a greater injury to the feelings of its
>   object. An *indignity* is, specifically, treatment that is unworthy —
>   an affront, insult, injury, or outrage from which one's condition or
>   character should have saved one: as, Zenobia was subjected to the
>   indignity of being led in chains at Aurelian's triumph. An *outrage*,
>   primarily involving the idea of violence to the person, is a wanton
>   transgression of law or propriety in any way, the perpetration of that
>   which is shamefully contrary to the dictates of humanity or even
>   decency; toward a person it is a combination of insult with indignity;
>   hence it often stands for extreme abusiveness of language. It has
>   freedom of use sufficient to make proper such expressions as, an
>   outrage to his feelings, an outrage to all decency.

I got this from [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/affront), which is a great resource for detecting subtle nuances and differences in the shades of meaning between similar words.  My very recent answer to your [other similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66865/whats-the-difference-between-paltry-and-meager) already discusses the value of this resource, so I won't delve into it again here.

I hope you'll use that resource in the future when you want to know the "difference" between two or three similar words.  Teach a man to fish, and he'll fish for a lifetime.

My curtness here is only because I don't want to repeat myself; please don't feel affronted, I don't mean any offense.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. It's like instead of giving me another cup of milk you gave me a whole cow!

Answer (score 2):

To take umbrage is to take offence - these are equivalent in meaning ([see dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take+umbrage))

To affront is to insult someone, so it is slightly different.

Both offence and affront have a noun form, whereas umbrage is no longer used except in the "take umbrage" form.