# What's the difference between "paltry" and "meager"?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between "paltry" and "meager"? Any connotations?

Comment: For one thing, *paltry* is stronger than *meager*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found at least one dictionary that listed *meager* as a definition of *paltry*, suggesting that the two words could be used interchangeably in some contexts, particularly if you are talking about an amount.

However, if you look up both these words on Wordnik, you see some subtle differences in their meaning.

[*Paltry*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/paltry) suggests something is contemptible, unimportant, and insignificant; while [*meager*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/meager) suggests something is deficient or scant.

When applied to a salary, then, a *paltry* salary wouldn't necessarily be lower than a *meager* salary, but it might suggest that the wages were insultingly low.

Although Wordnik lists both words as "equivalents" (you see that at the bottom of the page), the synonym list varies rather significantly.  Synonyms for *paltry* include: *worthless, contemptible, despicable*; synonyms for paltry include: *barren, gaunt, and impoverished*.

I strongly suggest looking at both pages on Wordnik, as those two web pages can provide much more information than my meager contribution.

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks for this link. I knew nothing about Wordnik. "those two web pages can provide much more information than my meager contribution" - So, had you said "my paltry contribution", would you have deprecated yourself then or insulted me? :)

Comment: @brilliant: It would have been self-deprecating, to be sure.  I tend to insult myself first, then try my very hardest to leave it there.   :^)

Answer (score 4):

- **Etymology**: *Meagre* is from [Old French](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=meager), meaning *thin* originally. **Paltry**'s origins are [less certain](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=paltry), but it is agreed that originally it meant *ragged* or *torn*.
- **Meaning**: Apart from the shared meanings of *less* and *poor quality*, **meagre** can also mean *lean* or *emaciated*, keeping in line with its roots.
- **Usage**: As Kris notes in his comment, *paltry* is generally stronger than *meagre*. When you say "meagre salary", you just mean it is very less. OTOH, "paltry salary" is stronger: it is somewhat of an equivalent to saying, "The salary is ridiculously low."